# Всем Привет! Подскажите, как правильно сделать алгоритм подбора программистов по параметрам?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Такая проблема. Есть программа, которая должна подбирать программиста по параметрам.
Параметры следующие[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пользователь может выбрать только один из пунктов, а также пропускать. Пример: **ПХП, - , ВебРазработка, - .**

И когда программа находит мне программистов по выбранным параметрам, то выдается список программистов, рисунок ниже[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне можно отсортировать программистов, чтобы по параметрам пользователя отобразились от лучших к менее лучшим.

Думал над обязательными критериями для сравнения - **Язык, Рейтинг, СПец**

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: можно отсортировать по стажу и по кол-ву языков, уже будет неплохо. Но по факту, только опытный интервьювер скажет, что лучше

Comment: Надо просто составить математическое выражение критерия "лучшести", ну или соответствия заданному набору параметров - что в свою очередь требует существования весовых коэффициентов соответствия... в общем, задачка-то административная, а вовсе даже не программная или алгоритмическая.

Comment: всегда можно прикрутить нейроночку и обучить. прям задача один в один. и найдет все весовые коэффициенты.

Comment: Определите **критерий**, какой программист лучше, какой хуже — тогда можно будет о чем-то говорить...

Comment: я думаю, что автор вопроса как раз об этом и спрашивает